# i want all the image should be of same size ..even if though it have more properties then the other image

Tags: html, css, angular

this is what i have tried ,i have changed the object-fit to cover.I wonder how I could make an image resize along with the properties increase, here is what I have done so far.

Any ideas on how could I make this?

```
<img mat-card-image style="height: 250px; object-fit: cover "src="./assets/imgs/orbi/products/{{prod.providerComp}}/{{prod.prodImg}}">.
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to copy your current code. Please add if possible. :)

Comment: kindly add your css code

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: You don't need any third party library, `background-image: contain` does the trick

Answer (score -1):

There are many available third party libraries online, which you could use to convert an image to given size (height and width) without it getting distorted.
Imgix is one such example though it is paid.
this is another example of a npm package to change the size
https://alligator.io/angular/resizing-images-in-browser-ng2-img-max/